# PHP X-Mailer not sending all fields

Tags: php, html, forms

I am by no means a developer. Self-taught, but can usually wing it enough to make things happen. Working on company website for boss, and having trouble with the form. Regardless of how I try to define the PHP variable, SOME are not sending the input value to the e-mail. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, thank you in advance for your help! This is what's not showing:

Website: 
Average Monthly Volume: 
Preferred Contact Method:

Here is what I have so far:

**HTML FORM:**

```
<div class="product-screens2">
    <div style="padding:200px">
        <div class="form">
          <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
          <div id="errormessage">Please retry.</div>
          <form action="form-email" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Business Name" />
               </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="business_site" placeholder="Business Website"  />
                 </div>
           <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="avgvolume" placeholder="Average Monthly Volume" />
              </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="contactmethod" placeholder="Preferred Contact Method" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Brief Description of Goods or Services Sold"></textarea>
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" title="Send Message">SUBMIT</button></div>
          </form>

      </div></div>
</div>
```

**PHP MAILER SCRIPT**

```
<?php

/***************** Configuration *****************/

// Enter your email, where you want to receive the messages.
$contact_email_to = "Support@XXXXX.com";

// Subject prefix
$contact_subject_prefix = "Message From XXXXX Website: ";

// Name too short error text
$contact_error_name = "Name is too short or empty!";

// Email invalid error text
$contact_error_email = "Please enter a valid email!";

// Subject too short error text
$contact_error_subject = "Subject is too short or empty!";

// Message too short error text
$contact_error_message = "Too short message! Please enter something.";



/********** Do not edit from the below line ***********/

if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
  die('Sorry Request must be Ajax POST');
}

if(isset($_POST)) {

  $name = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  $subject = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $message = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $business_site = $_POST["business_site"];
  $avgvolume = $_POST["avgvolume"];
  $contactmethod = $_POST["contactmethod"];


  if(strlen($name)<4){
    die($contact_error_name);
  }

  if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    die($contact_error_email);
  }

  if(strlen($message)<3){
    die($contact_error_subject);
  }

  if(strlen($message)<3){
    die($contact_error_message);
  }

  if(!isset($contact_email_from)) {
    $contact_email_from = "contactform@" . @preg_replace('/^www\./','', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
  }

  $sendemail = mail($contact_email_to, $contact_subject_prefix . $subject,
    "Name: $name" . PHP_EOL .
    "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL .
    "Business: $subject" . PHP_EOL .
    "Website: $business_site" . PHP_EOL .
    "Average Monthly Volume: $avgvolume" . PHP_EOL .
    "Preferred Contact Method: $contactmethod" . PHP_EOL .
    "Business Description: $message" . PHP_EOL .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()
  );

  if( $sendemail ) {
    echo 'OK';
  } else {
    echo 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: What's with action="form-email"? shouldn't it be something like action="form-email.php"?

Comment: name="name" you have this in multiple places in teh HTML, which can be the cause for website, avgvolume, contact method to not come and for email it might be because of the FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL, make sure you have valid email entered

Comment: Thank you @codisfy! I don't know how I missed the "name" being reused... Worked after I fixed that. Appreciate it!